# `assert` is a keyword, compiling with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, javac, assertion

I'm compiling a Java project with Gradle.  When I run `gradle build`, I get:

> Task :compileJava FAILED
>   /home/mvh/projects/research/DPM/src/main/java/DPM/bandera/Bandera.java:102: error: as of release 1.4, 'assert' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier
>       public static void assert(boolean expr) {
>                          ^
>     (use -source 1.3 or lower to use 'assert' as an identifier)
>   1 error

Apparently when compiling with javac, the solution is to add the argument `-source 1.3`, per the error message.  So I tried adding this argument in gradle as follows:

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs << '-ea'
}
```

I also tried `enableassertions`, `-enableassertions`, and `ea` in place of `-ea`.

I also tried this:

```
test {
    enableAssertions = true
}
```

Also to no avail.  How can I get my gradle build file to enable assertions when it compiles my project?  Thanks!

Comment: No, the solution is to modify your source code to not use `assert` as an identifier.

Comment: I agree with Andreas. Your code has a problem, not gradle. Fix the real problem, instead of working around symptoms. And no, compiling with java 1.3 level ... that is like a really really really bad idea. Really.

Comment: I'm confused. If you compile with `-source 1.3`, i.e. simulating old code where assertions didn't exist, why are you trying to *run* the code with assertions enabled? What would be the point of enabling assertions if the code is compiled without them?

Comment: @Andreas I don't think it's specifically a good idea to compile with 1.3, I only tried it because the error message seemed to suggest I should.  I am not very knowledgeable about gradle or Java and am very open to suggestions.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel Then this is the important part of the error message: *"'assert' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier"*, which means that you need to edit your source code and stop using `assert` as a method name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried?

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs << '-source 1.3'
}
```

I have to warn you this way you loose all "modern" language features (like generics).

**PS:**
Proper solution will be rename `assert` method in class `Bandera`.

**EDIT**
Correct way to set this flag is

```
compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.3
}
```

Renaming method is better way to solve this issue.

Comment: That isn't a "warning", but a simple indication of a "no go". Still, it would theoretically solve the problem, so have a vote for creativity ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat yes, but if OP want it what can I do?

Comment: I know, we only hand out shot guns. Where people aim that thing, not our problem.

Comment: This doesn't work for me: > * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> invalid flag: -source 1.3

Comment: I can change Bandera though, that's a good idea.  I'll try that tomorrow if possible.

Comment: Renaming method fixed it.  Thanks.